# Is there a feature in authorize.net or usaepay for following purpose?

Tags: java, spring, payment, authorize.net, usaepay

I have scenario like this :

1. We have an app where there can be service provider and service receiver. They both have to register in our app.
2. Service receiver will pay the Service provider by paying for the service via our App and our app will cut certain commission from the payment.
3. Currently, our app is on Android/iOS and our Backend is in Java/Spring.

We have used Stripe and PayPal for similar cases in our other projects. And for this project the client wants us to use authorize.net/usaepay. We did some research over the docs but actually couldn't find a solution for similar scenario.

So my question to the community is : Does authorize.net/usaepay have such feature for our requirement ? Or is authorize.net/usaepay appropriate for this scenario ?

Comment: No, you would need to charge two payments if you wish to divide the payment into two parts.

Comment: @John Conde, thanks for reply. So it's not possible, right?

Comment: Right. It is not possible.

Comment: @JohnConde, and does usaepay support this feature ?